# Ecobee API: Documentation is for curl not sure how to translate to Python

Tags: python-3.x, rest, curl, ecobee, ecobee-api

The Ecobee API documentation shows this as a way to access their API:

```
#curl -s -H 'Content-Type: text/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN' 'https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat?format=json&body=\{"selection":\{"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","includeRuntime":true\}\}'
```

I have used that code in curl and it seems to work. 
However when I try what I think is the equivalent python code it doesn't work.

(I really don't know curl well at all. What I know I know from a few hours of internet research.)

the code I am using:

```
import requests

headers = {"Content-Type": "text/json", "Authorization": "Bearer  AUTH_TOKEN"}
response = requests.get('https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat?format=json&body=\{"selection":\{"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","includeRuntime":"true"\}\}', headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

When I send this I get:

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": 4,
    "message": "Serialization error. Malformed json. Check your request and parameters are valid."
  }
}
```

Not sure what could be wrong with my json formating. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to URL-escape the special characters in the parameters.

Doing this by hand can be messy and prone to mistakes. I'm not a Python expert but initial research suggests using the `params` option built into Python's `request.get()`. For example:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat'
TOKEN = 'ECOBEEAPIACCESSTOKEN'
header = {'Content-Type':'text/json', 'Authorization':'Bearer ' + TOKEN}
payload = {'json': '{"selection":{"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","includeRuntime":"true"}}'}
response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=header)

print(response.url)
print(response.text)
```